# Verbs with two objects

Tags: verbs, direct-objects, indirect-objects, ditransitive-verbs

Some verbs are used with two objects (indirect-; somebody, direct-object; something). e.g.

> I gave him a watch for his birthday.
>   Could you send me the report?
>   I will lend you some money.
>   She told me a story.

This sentences can also be used like this (I think):

> I gave a watch to him for his birthday.
>   Could you send the report to me?
>   I will lend some money to you.
>   She told a story to me.

But these verbs cannot be used like above sentences:

> I would like you to explain me this theory. (X)
>   I would like you to explain this theory to me (O)
>   Can you suggest me a good cardiologist? (X)
>   Can you suggest a good cardiologist to me? (O)
>   Please describe me your job. (X)
>   Please describe your job to me. (O)

So my questions are:

1. Can we explain differences between these verbs of which some are used only [direct- + to (or any prepositions) + indirect-verb], not [indirect- + direct-verb] and the others are used both.
2. "inform" is used like this (inform + indirect- + preposition + direct):
   "Please inform us of any changes of address."
   How to explain this verbs like "inform"? What's the difference? What is preposition "of" here?

Comment: Some verbs are ditranstive and thus can take Oi and Od. Others are monotransotive and require a PP with _to_ or _for_ (and sometimes _of_) to express the recipient or beneficiary. I'm not sure why this is the case - I suppose it's just the way the language has evolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible for a verb in English to want 0, 1, or 2 objects - some only accept a specific number of objects, some work with 0 or 1 objects but with a change in meaning.  It's just part of the meaning of the verb.

A verb that "wants" 2 objects can always be expressed in the form "{verb} {indirect-object} {direct-object}" with no prepositions.

> I gave him the ball.

Other forms are possible ...

> I gave the ball to him

but if the verb wants 2 objects, the first form will always work.  If it doesn't work, one of them is not an object but an other type of complement.

> Please inform us of any changes of address.
>
> Please inform any changes of address of us (fails - we're still asking who is being informed.)

So "any changes of address" is not an object and *inform* is not a two-object verb.